# React Native. Requiring paths from .env vars

Tags: javascript, react-native, environment-variables

Im trying to require paths from .env vars but this doesnt work, and I dont know if its because its not possible to require dynamic paths ,or if its because of the order in which things get compiled, either way, the workaround I found atm is to use base64 encoded images.

***Just for better context:*** Im using `react-native-config` just to point which .env file RN should look at, because currently `react-native-config` is not working properly in RN 0.60+ so im using it with `react-native-build-config` to expose those vars to my .js (If you can give me any sugestions here, I'll be glad)

e.g.

```
//.env
IMAGE_SOURCE='base64SourceHere'
```

.

```
//myComponent.js 
const imageSrc = BuildConfig.IMAGE_SOURCE

<Image style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }} source={ uri: imageSrc } resizeMode="contain"/>
```

**My question here is**.. Is base64 encoded images a bad practice? If it is and even if its not, any sugestions? Can I use uri for local file paths?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**What is Base64?**

Base64 is an encoding and decoding technique used to convert binary data to an American Standard for Information Interchange (ASCII) text format, and vice versa.

Base64 is a relatively efficient way of encoding binary data it will, on average still increase the file size for more than 25%. This not only increases your bandwidth bill, but also increases the download time.

**CPU Overhead**

When delivering images in Base64, the browser first needs to decode the Base64 encoded strings and then decode the images as well, which introduces an extra layer of unnecessary work.

**Caching Issues**

The third issue is perhaps the biggest performance killer, but perhaps not the most obvious at first glance. When a user accesses your website, the browser will automatically cache the images locally and then load them directly from your disk when visiting the same page again. Due to how Base64 works, the browser is unable to store the images locally so it will always need to fetch them from your server or CDN which creates extra load on your server as well as increases your bandwidth bill.

Source link:[doc](https://bunnycdn.com/blog/why-optimizing-your-images-with-base64-is-almost-always-a-bad-idea/)

Other More info :[doc](https://www.davidbcalhoun.com/2011/when-to-base64-encode-images-and-when-not-to/)

**Base64 image Useful:**

It's only useful for very tiny images. Base64 encoded files are larger than the original.

Bas64 encoded images are good practice for a small size (KB) images. For bigger size image you can use . Thumbnails .

How to handle images in react native,Check this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images).

---

**Read local image in react-native:**

You can use [react-native-fs](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) to get directories which works for both platform

```
var RNFS = require('react-native-fs');

<Image source={{uri: 'file://' + RNFS.DocumentDirectoryPath + '/directory/example.png'}} />
```

---

**Set up .env in react native application**

-->you can use **react-native-config**. It allows you to specify a .env file to import variables into your code.For installation check this:[doc](https://github.com/luggit/react-native-config)

-->  **react-native-dotenv** is another solution for .env file in React Native.For installation check this:[doc](https://github.com/goatandsheep/react-native-dotenv)

Comment: Thanks alot for your time! I'll look deeply in to `react-native-fs` and if it solves my problem I'll check to accept your answer!

Comment: For a little bit more context, Im developping a white label app, thats why I need dynamic paths.. For me to be able to build whatever version fo the app on the go. With that in mind what I can do is require everything in a .js file and with the .env vars just export what I want to my component. Of course this means that im requering x * (number of different apps in my white label), but is this that bad?

Comment: Also check this:https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-gracefully-use-environment-variables-in-a-react-native-app/

Comment: Oh, im sorry if I miss communicated. On  my post I already said I was using react-native-config and more or less explained some of the issues but thats not the main problem, at leat right now. In my comment I asked if requiring every image in one .js file is that bad.

Comment: You meas,you want all images of your project keeps into one .js file,Am i right?And you want dynamic import all images?If i am right to understan you ,then yes sure you can definitely do it.Check for reference exmaple:https://dev.to/emilios1995/dynamic-imports-in-react-native-9k5

Comment: Yes, you are right and that example is great! But do you know if thats a bad practice?

Comment: In my opinion,its not bad practice,but putting all images in const and fetch by array,its little tricky .And if you have more images to display in your app ,you should call from network server (api,firebase).